# Which database model should I use for dynamic modification of entities/properties during runtime?

Tags: python, database, dynamic, sqlalchemy, redis

I am thinking about creating an open source data management web application for various types of data.

A privileged user must be able to

- add new entity types (for example a 'user' or a 'family')
- add new properties to entity types (for example 'gender' to 'user')
- remove/modify entities and properties

These will be common tasks for the privileged user. He will do this through the web interface of the application. In the end, all data must be searchable and sortable by all types of users of the application. Two questions trouble me:

**a) How should the data be stored in the database? Should I dynamically add/remove database tables and/or columns during runtime?**

I am no database expert. I am stuck with the imagination that in terms of relational databases, the application has to be able to dynamically add/remove tables (entities) and/or columns (properties) at runtime. And I don't like this idea. Likewise, I am thinking if such dynamic data should be handled in a NoSQL database.

Anyway, I believe that this kind of problem has an intelligent canonical solution, which I just did not find and think of so far. *What is the best approach for this kind of dynamic data management?*

**b) How to implement this in Python using an ORM or NoSQL?**

If you recommend using a relational database model, then I would like to use SQLAlchemy. However, I don't see how to dynamically create tables/columns with an ORM at runtime. This is one of the reasons why I hope that there is a much better approach than creating tables and columns during runtime. *Is the recommended database model efficiently implementable with SQLAlchemy?*

If you recommend using a NoSQL database, which one? I like using Redis -- *can you imagine an efficient implementation based on Redis?*

Thanks for your suggestions!

**Edit in response to some comments:**

The idea is that all instances ("rows") of a certain entity ("table") share the same set of properties/attributes ("columns"). However, it will be perfectly valid if certain instances have an empty value for certain properties/attributes.

Basically, users will search the data through a simple form on a website. They query for e.g. all instances of an entity E with property P having a value V higher than T. The result can be sorted by the value of any property.

The datasets won't become too large. Hence, I think even the stupidest approach would still lead to a working system. However, I am an enthusiast and I'd like to apply modern and appropriate technology as well as I'd like to be aware of theoretical bottlenecks. I want to use this project in order to gather experience in designing a "Pythonic", state-of-the-art, scalable, and reliable web application.

I see that the first comments tend to recommending a NoSQL approach. Although I really like Redis, it looks like it would be stupid not to take advantage of the Document/Collection model of Mongo/Couch. I've been looking into mongodb and mongoengine for Python. By doing so, do I take steps into the right direction?

**Edit 2 in response to some answers/comments:**

From most of your answers, I conclude that the dynamic creation/deletion of tables and columns in the relational picture is **not** the way to go. This already is valuable information. Also, one opinion is that the whole idea of the dynamic modification of entities and properties could be bad design.

As exactly this dynamic nature should be the main purpose/feature of the application, I don't give up on this. From the theoretical point of view, I accept that performing operations on a dynamic data model must necessarily be slower than performing operations on a static data model. This is totally fine.

Expressed in an abstract way, the application needs to manage

1. the *data layout*, i.e. a "dynamic list" of valid entity types and a "dynamic list" of properties for each valid entity type
2. the *data itself*

I am looking for an intelligent and efficient way to implement this. From your answers, it looks like NoSQL is the way to go here, which is another important conclusion.

Comment: What sort of queries do you anticipate running - how will "non-privileged" users search your data?

Comment: In terms of NoSQL, entity types and properties are a matter of validation, not structure. Thus, you need to operate on top of the NoSQL client driver to achieve this.

Comment: A document database like [couch](http://www.couchbase.com) or [mongo](http://www.mongodb.org) is ideally suited for this task.

Comment: Thanks for your comments so far. I added some more information to the question above.

Comment: I found myself in similar situation, except I am using Ruby on Rails with Mongoid (a wrapper for MongoDB). I can easily add models and fields on the fly, but deleting fields has been problematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, if you conceptualize your entities as "documents," then this whole problem maps onto a no-sql solution pretty well.  As commented, you'll need to have some kind of model layer that sits on top of your document store and performs tasks like validation, and perhaps enforces (or encourages) some kind of schema, because there's no implicit backend requirement that entities in the same collection (parallel to table) share schema.

Allowing privileged users to change your schema concept (as opposed to just adding fields to individual documents - that's easy to support) will pose a little bit of a challenge - you'll have to handle migrating the existing data to match the new schema automatically.

Reading your edits, Mongo supports the kind of searching/ordering you're looking for, and will give you the support for "empty cells" (documents lacking a particular key) that you need.

If I were you (and I happen to be working on a similar, but simpler, product at the moment), I'd stick with Mongo and look into a lightweight web framework like Flask to provide the front-end.  You'll be on your own to provide the model, but you won't be fighting against a framework's implicit modeling choices.

Answer (score 20):

The SQL or NoSQL choice is not your problem. You need to read little more about database design in general. As you said, you're not a database expert(and you don't need to be), but
you absolutely **must** study a little more the RDBMS paradigm.

It's a common mistake for amateur enthusiasts to choose a NoSQL solution. Sometimes NoSQL
is a good solution, **most** of the times is not.

Take for example MongoDB, which you mentioned(and is one of the good NoSQL solutions I've tried). Schema-less, right? Err.. not exactly. You see when something is schema-less means no constraints, validation, etc. But your application's models/entities can't stand on thin air! Surely there will be some constraints and validation logic which you **will** implement on your software layer. So I give you [mongokit](http://namlook.github.com/mongokit/)! I will just quote from the project's description this tiny bit

> MongoKit brings structured schema and validation layer on top of the
>   great pymongo driver

Hmmm... unstructured became structured.

At least we don't have SQL right? Yeah, we don't. We have a different [query language](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying) which is of course inferior to SQL. At least you don't need to resort to map/reduce for basic queries(see CouchDB).

Don't get me wrong, NoSQL(and especially MongoDB) has its purpose, but most of the times these technologies are used for the wrong reason.

Also, if you care about serious persistence and data integrity forget about NoSQL solutions. 
All these technologies are too experimental to keep your serious data. By researching a bit who(except Google/Amazon) uses NoSQL solutions and for what exactly, you will find that almost **no one** uses it for keeping their important data. They mostly use them for logging, messages and real time data. Basically anything to off-load some burden from their SQL db storage.

Redis, in my opinion, is probably the only project who is going to survive the NoSQL explosion unscathed. Maybe because it doesn't advertise itself as NoSQL, but as a key-value store, which is exactly what it is and a pretty damn good one! Also they seem serious about [persistence](http://antirez.com/post/redis-persistence-demystified.html). It is a swiss army knife, but not a good solution to replace entirely your RDBMS.

I am sorry, I said too much :)

So here is my suggestion:

1) Study the RDBMS model a bit.

2) Django is a good framework if **most** of your project is going to use an RDBMS.

3) Postgresql rocks! Also keep in mind that version 9.2 will bring native [JSON](http://arstechnica.com/business/2012/01/native-json-features-submitted-for-postgresql-92/) support.  You could dump all your 'dynamic' properties in there and you could use a secondary storage/engine to perform queries(map/reduce) on said properties. Have your cake and eat it too!

4) For serious search capabilities consider specialized engines like [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

EDIT: 6 April 2013

5) [django-ext-hstore](https://github.com/niwibe/djorm-ext-hstore) gives you access to postgresql hstore type. It's similar
to a python dictionary and you can perform queries on it, with the limitation that
you can't have nested dictionaries as values. Also the value of key can be only
of type `string`.

Have fun

---

**Update** in response to OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672939/which-database-model-should-i-use-for-dynamic-modification-of-entities-propertie/10712269#comment14043939_10712269)

> 0) Consider the application 'contains data' and has already been used
>   for a while

I am not sure if you mean that it contains data in a legacy dbms or you are just
trying to say that "imagine that the DB is not empty and consider the following points...".
In the former case, it seems a migration issue(completely different question), in the latter, well OK.

> 1) Admin deletes entity "family" and all related data

Why should someone eliminate completely an entity(table)? Either your application has to do with families, houses, etc or it doesn't. Deleting instances(rows) of families is understandable of course.

> 2) Admin creates entity "house"

Same with #1. If you introduce a brand new entity in your app then most probably it will encapsulate semantics and business logic, for which new code must be written. This happens to all applications as they evolve through time and of course warrants a creation of a new table, or maybe [ALTER](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html)ing an existing one. But this process is not a part of the functionality of your application. i.e. it happens rarely, and is a migration/refactoring issue.

> 3) Admin adds properties "floors", "age", ..

Why? Don't we know beforehand that a `House` has floors? That a `User` has a gender?
Adding and removing, dynamically, this type of attributes is not a feature, but a design flaw. It is part of the analysis/design phase to identify your entities and their respective properties.

> 4) Privileged user adds some houses.

Yes, he is adding an instance(row) to the existing entity(table) `House`.

> 5) User searches for all houses with at least five floors cheaper than
>   100 $

A perfectly valid query which can be achieved with either SQL or NoSQL solution.
In django it would be something along those lines:

```
House.objects.filter(floors__gte=5, price__lt=100)
```

provided that `House` has the attributes `floors` and `price`. But if you need to do text-based queries, then neither SQL nor NoSQL will be satisfying enough. Because you don't want to implement [faceting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faceted_classification) or [stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) on your own! You will use some of the already discussed solutions(Solr, ElasticSearch, etc).

Some more general notes:

The examples you gave about `Houses`, `Users` and their properties, do not warrant any dynamic schema. Maybe you simplified your example just to make your point, but you talk about adding/removing `Entities(tables)` as if they are rows in a db. Entities are supposed to be a big deal in an application. They define the purpose of your application and its functionality. As such, they can't change every minute.

Also you said:

```
The idea is that all instances ("rows") of a certain entity ("table") share the same set of properties/attributes ("columns"). However, it will be perfectly valid if certain instances have an empty value for certain properties/attributes.
```

This seems like a common case where an attribute has `null=True`.

And as a final note, I would like to suggest to you to try both approaches(SQL and NoSQL), since it doesn't seem like your career depends on this project. It will be a beneficiary experience, as you will understand first-hand, the cons and pros of each approach. Or even how to "blend" these approaches together.

Comment: Wait, so, why do you wan to make unstructured data (the strength of NoSQL databases) structured?

Comment: @DhaivatPandya exactly! That's my point. You don't like structure at first, but later on you understand that it is somewhat necessary. You don't like SQL and later on you invent an inferior language. :)

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not sure that I agree with you. Structure is not needed for all applications, and, when you need to move quickly, it often gets in the way.

Comment: Well, wishful thinking on your part. Structure is needed everywhere! You either gonna have it in your DB layer, or your business logic layer. There is no way around it.

Comment: I think we all agree that in any case a certain schema and the corresponding validation is necessary in order to keep code and data synchronized. Therefore, Mongokit, Mongoengine, Ming, and whatsoever are very convenient libraries.

Comment: @rantanplan: Your point is that a relational database could also fit to my problem. How would you represent/store entities and properties? I guess you would *not* create/remove columns and tables during runtime, would you?

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke No way. RDBMS is not meant to be used like that. I think that your entities(tables) and properties(columns) are modeled wrong. I still don't see the infinitely dynamic nature of your entities. I would need a more concrete picture of what you're trying to achieve, in order to show you how to represent entities/properties in your situation.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke Also don't forget about the PgSQL and JSON type on my 3rd point. Basically with this you get the quality of a serious DBMS and the dynamicity of a NoSQL. Just don't over do it, otherwise you're invalidating the purpose of the RDBMS.

Comment: *exactly*. So, you will need a flexible structure.

Comment: @DhaivatPandya I don't think we are on the same page, you need to re-read my answer on this question. You can store your data on plain CSV files. How's that for schema-less? Now answer me this, are you or are your not going to validate the data that goes into this CSV file, in your application's business logic? How hard is it to understand this? That's why mongokit exists.

Comment: There is also ElasticSearch on Lucene which is used by Greylog2. It is quite fast compared to Solr (which also uses Lucene btw).

Comment: @Barry Yeah and I see it is supported by django-haystack. I haven't used it though. I originally went with Solr because it seemed the most popular(safe choice). Worth looking into though.

Comment: @rantanplan Ah neat.  Sometimes what you know best is least risky when it counts.  Othertimes, it might be ok to try out a new tech.

Comment: @rantanplan in response to "I would need a more concrete picture ... in order to show you how to represent entities/properties in your situation": 0) Consider the application 'contains data' and has already been used for a while. 1) Admin deletes entity "family" and all related data. 2) Admin creates entity "house". 3) Admin adds properties "floors", "age", ... . 4) Privileged user adds some houses. 5) User searches for all houses with at least five floors cheaper than 100 $. -- There will be O(10) entities and O(100) properties per entity.

Comment: Those numbers are realistic for use cases I can imagine so far. However, if I had to formulate the requirement more generally, I would just say the implementation should scale very well with the number of entities and properties.

Comment: I conclude from your update that the requested features (dynamic modification of entities/properties) are a design flaw by themselves. However, yes, in this application I want a privileged user to be able to modify/remove properties. And yes, he should also be able to remove an entire entity (which will happen rarely).

Comment: Exactly this should be *the one special feature* of this application. I agree that operations on a static set of entities/properties can be implemented more efficiently. However, my question is: how can I implement the dynamic scheme most efficiently?

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke Well if that is the one special feature of your application I see 2 ways. Either re-model your entities as instance(rows) of a more abstract model called..hmm... *Entity*? Or do use a NoSQL solution.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke actually that's my problem. I don't get if you just have a preconceived notion of what constitutes an `Entity`, `Instance`in your app, or that it really has to be that dynamic. I mean if you want to do it just for the sake of doing it, ok. But I really can't tell if it serves some functional purpose for the application you want to build. In any case, just avoid doing it on an RDBMS and prefer the NoSQL solution if you really want/need to do that.

Comment: For the moment, I am sure that the dynamic nature as I described it makes sense. As you may have already noticed, you got the bounty for a lot of very valuable insights and discussion. The solution seems to be NoSQL, which was also nicely elaborated by @AndrewRoberts who gets the "accepted answer". Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke No one holds the absolute truth and the answer you chose is perfectly valid, since you deem necessary to have such a dynamic nature in your app. You're welcome.

Comment: @rantanplan sometimes there are situations where you want to create dynamic data, add dynamic fields at runtime. The typical example is in a CRM where users want to add their own custom fields to a model. You would still recommend SQL for this?

Comment: @Donato  it just so happens that I work in a product of this kind. We do have custom fields(indeed very important in these type of apps) and we use RDBMS(MySQL). Usually you have a table with the *declarations* of the custom fields and another which holds the values(instances) of the declarations. It's hard to do it cleanly, but you can do it nonetheless. You could also do it by storing the info in a JSON blob, but then you lose some constraints and validations offered by the RDBMS. PostgreSQL's new JSON types might be perfect for this, unfortunately I don't have the luxury to use it.

Comment: @rantanplan how are you storing datatypes? Some custom fields might be datetime, others might be text, while others might be integers. You won't know this until runtime.

Comment: @Donato well you do know beforehand how many different types are going to be right? So you just create a column for every datatype you're going to offer. e.g. number_value, datetime_value, text_value etc etc. And depending on what custom field type you're using at a given moment, you use the appropriate column value.

Comment: @rantanplan are you using an ORM to accomplish this? I am not familiar with any ORM implementing the ActiveRecord pattern which can handle this scenerio out of the box.

Comment: @Donato you can do what I described with or without an ORM. It's simple database modeling. In general I use either Django's ORM or SQLAlchemy.

Comment: This answer is too large. A big part of the answer at the end tries to deny the problem (the need for dynamic definition of entities) that the first part of the answer tries to solve (when proposing specific technologies).

Concrete answers are good in order to keep a clean knowledge base for others.

Comment: "Why should someone eliminate completely an entity(table)?" Answer: The software is a part of a bigger system "The Enterprise". The software responds to the requirements at a Business Layer scope defined by the Stakeholder. The proper existence of the software system modifies the Business and give more ideas to the Stakeholder of what can the technology achieve and more ideas to Software Developers of the business  problem domain. The software is just a projection of the Business at the informative space, if something changes there it need to be reflected on the software.

Comment: "Don't we know beforehand that a House has floors?" Answer: Because the level of Abstraction (http://bit.ly/1VUCSis)  can change according to the needs of the Stakeholder. The proper question presume a Waterfall model of software development (http://bit.ly/1Mjxcgn). Nowadays software development is iterative and incremental (http://bit.ly/1Mjxm7i) the software starts as a prototype that grows on every cycle and evolves forever. Nevertheless you should decide a level of maturity in which you will deploy it. Once deployed it is harder to maintain rigid db models, then we need user-defined data.

Comment: @yucer all these fall under the "migration" concept. The software always evolves, so trying to predict how it will evolve, or making it generic enough to cover all possible future cases is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @rantanplan Precisely "predict" how the software will evolve is the cornerstone of a good architecture. And yes, when your framework is more prepared  to face those future cases then you will spent fewer efforts on migration.

Comment: @yucer that goes against everything we've learned about software engineering. "Agile" for example is the exact opposite of what you describe. It's good to have opinions, but there are problems we have solved and things we haven't. These are "solved" problems, which you can read about in relevant books or from engineers in large companies(Google, FB, Amazon, etc etc) that have talked about it. And to be honest I don't understand why you have  to revive a 3 year old question on SO to talk about such things. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ is a better place.

Answer (score 6):

What you're asking about is a common requirement in many systems -- how to extend a core data model to handle user-defined data.  That's a popular requirement for packaged software (where it is typically handled one way) and open-source software (where it is handled another way).

The earlier advice to learn more about RDBMS design generally can't hurt.  What I will add to that is, don't fall into the trap of re-implementing a relational database in your own application-specific data model!  I have seen this done many times, usually in packaged software.  Not wanting to expose the core data model (or permission to alter it) to end users, the developer creates a generic data structure and an app interface that allows the end user to define entities, fields etc. but not using the RDBMS facilities.  That's usually a mistake because it's hard to be nearly as thorough or bug-free as what a seasoned RDBMS can just do for you, and it can take a lot of time.  It's tempting but IMHO not a good idea.

Assuming the data model changes are global (shared by all users once admin has made them), the way I would approach this problem would be to create an app interface to sit between the admin user and the RDBMS, and apply whatever rules you need to apply to the data model changes, but then pass the final changes to the RDBMS.  So for example, you may have rules that say entity names need to follow a certain format, new entities are allowed to have foreign keys to existing tables but must always use the DELETE CASCADE rule, fields can only be of certain data types, all fields must have default values etc.  You could have a very simple screen asking the user to provide entity name, field names & defaults etc. and then generate the SQL code (inclusive of all your rules) to make these changes to your database.

Some common rules & how you would address them would be things like:

-- if a field is not null and has a default value, and there are already existing records in the table before that field was added by the admin, update existing records to have the default value while creating the field (multiple steps -- add field allowing null; update all existing records; alter the table to enforce not null w/ default) -- otherwise you wouldn't be able to use a field-level integrity rule)

-- new tables must have a distinct naming pattern so you can continue to distinguish your core data model from the user-extended data model, i.e. core and user-defined have different RDBMS owners (dbo. vs. user.) or prefixes (none for core, __ for user-defined) or somesuch.

-- it is OK to add fields to tables that are in the core data model (as long as they tolerate nulls or have a default), and it is OK for admin to delete fields that admin added to core data model tables, but admin cannot delete fields that were defined as part of the core data model.

In other words -- use the power of the RDBMS to define the tables and manage the data, but in order to ensure whatever conventions or rules you need will always be applied, do this by building an app-to-DB admin function, instead of giving the admin user direct DB access.

If you really wanted to do this via the DB layer only, you could probably achieve the same by creating a bunch of stored procedures and triggers that would implement the same logic (and who knows, maybe you would do that anyway for your app).  That's probably more of a question of how comfortable are your admin users working in the DB tier vs. via an intermediary app.

---

So to answer your questions directly:

(1) Yes, add tables and columns at run time, but think about the rules you will need to have to ensure your app can work even once user-defined data is added, and choose a way to enforce those rules (via app or via DB / stored procs or whatever) when you process the table & field changes.

(2) This issue isn't strongly affected by your choice of SQL vs. NoSQL engine.  In every case, you have a core data model and an extended data model.  If you can design your app to respond to a dynamic data model (e.g. add new fields to screens when fields are added to a DB table or whatever) then your app will respond nicely to changes in both the core and user-defined data model.  That's an interesting challenge but not much affected by choice of DB implementation style.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! However, adding tables/columns at runtime is contradictory to @rantanplan's "No way. RDBMS is not meant to be used like that." And.. do you see a way to achieve this using an ORM like SQLAlchemy?

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke To clarify `no way` as in "it is bad design" and not as in "can't be done". Also, I haven't met a project(Open or Closed sourced) that follows this pattern. This of course does not mean it doesn't exist. Also if there is an Open Source project that does that, I would like a pointer(link) in order to study it.

Comment: @ratanplan Take for example the CMS they are forced by its nature to allow user-defined data. I can not imagine a CMS with pre-packaged with all the possible entities that the user would need. Also many ERP systems have this problems and any other systems that try to reach a great degree of personalization. Basically they have three choices when realizing the user data at the RDBMS level: flexible columns (like this answer),  special tables with fixed columns that represent sparse matrices (like my answer) and special columns with non-relational structures (like the last update of your answer)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe doesn't matter the persistence engine of your model objects (RDBMS, NoSQL, etc...). The technology you're looking for is an index to search for and find your objects.

I think you need to find your objects using their schema. So, if the schema is defined dynamically and persisted on a database you can build dynamic search forms, etc.. Some kind of reference of the entity and attributes to the real objects is needed.

Give a look to the [Entity-Attribute-Model pattern (EAV)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model). This can be implemented over SQLAlchemy to use an RDBMS database as mean to store vertically your schema and data and relate thems.

You're entering in the field of the Semantic Web Programming, maybe you should read at less the first chapter of this book:

[Programming The Semantic Web](http://books.google.com.cu/books?id=XShw5YSHoRUC&lpg=PP1&dq=Programming%20the%20Semantic%20Web&pg=PR5#v=onepage&q=Programming%20the%20Semantic%20Web&f=false)

it tells the whole story of your problem: from rigid schemas to dynamic schemas, implemented first as a key-value store and later improved to a graph persistence over a relational model.

My opinion is that the best implementations of this could be achieved nowadays with **graph databases** and a very good example of current implementations are Berkeley DBs (some LDAP implementations use Berkeley DBs as a tech implementation to this indexing problem.)

Once in a graph model you could do some kind of "inferences" on the graph, making appear the DB with somekind of "intelligence". An example of this is stated on the book.

Comment: EAV is one of the most common anti-patterns. It is mentioned in SQL Antipatterns(ISBN:1934356557) among others. Also take a look here http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/01/29/name-value-pair-design/

Comment: EAV certanly makes not profit of the relational engine capabilities, but is a very flexible solution for this problem. As a matter of fact, it is more profitable as more user-defined data (and customization capabilities) you need to define  after deployment. Of course it is not for all the database, just for the sparse populated user-defined fields.